# Jquery toggle won't work after cloning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have cloned a list item using .clone in Jquery:

```
 $("#coll-selected-list li:contains(" + itemName + ")").clone().addClass("avgli").appendTo("#coll-grouped-list");
```

However, when I wish to toggle the newly added list item, it won't work for some reason. Any ideas?:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".avgli").toggle(function () {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('agg-drop')) {
            $(this).css("background", "#fff");
        }
    }, function () {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('agg-drop')) {
            $(this).css("background", "#676767");
        }
    }););

<ul id="coll-grouped-list" class="agg-drop">
       <li class="sortedli avgli" style="">Blah Blah</li>
       <li class="sortedli avgli" style="">Blah</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `clone(true)` instead. See the [**clone**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) docs.

`toggle` function adds event listeners to element, and you need to clone those listeners either.

Answer (score 0):

Live example : http://jsfiddle.net/K2uke/

And I have changed your script a bit so that it is not needed to double click to toggle effect.

By adding `.clone(true)` will clone the Element and Events.

> .clone( **[withDataAndEvents]** )
>
> **withDataAndEventsA** Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be
>   copied along with the elements.

Reference : http://api.jquery.com/clone/